# AdMob ads showing only in test device

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx, admob

I implemented `admob` ads to my game, it works on my Note3 which is the test device for this, but if i disable the Test device option or install it in other devices the ads dont show up! I have no idea what the problem is.

Ok again the question is : why ads are showing up only when the device is enabled by `adRequest.addTestDevice` ?

Maybe because i havent set yet the billing settings in admob website?

- My understanding about admob is equal to my understanding of nuclear energy, i mean its nothing or close to that, no kidding.
- Im using the correct AdUnitId.

Comment: Maybe there is not any ad in the inventory.

Answer (score 0):

Some error appears in Logcat? Might be some setting the size of the ad. Make sure the space allocated on the screen is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Hello stackoverflow community

I'm very sorry I didn't answer my question the same day I asked for it, stackoverflow didn't let me answer it I had to wait 82843hoursr, now, about the problem, all I had to do was to be patient and wait, it took like one hour to show up the first time in my game so I didn't realize that and I thought I was doing something wrong but everything was perfect so

Sorry my fault thank you guys (: